# How can I script checking if an rsa key is signed or not?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, rsa, phpseclib

I'm writing some PHP code, using phpseclib, which amongst other things, allows users to submit private keys.  As part of that, I want to check if a key is signed (aka Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421#section-4.6.1.1.1 according to vs 4 of the rfc).  Now can see from looking in the Crypt/RSA.php code in phpseclib, that it uses regex to search for the above in the Key data.  I know I could grep the key, to find that header, but I don't want my script to have to keep up with the rfc's in the future.  I'm assuming whatever box it's running on will have the current openssl.

So how do I ask openssl, what 'Proc-Type' a key is?  Currently I can ask it lots of things of an unsigned key.  Or I can give it a password and ask the same things of a signed key, but I can tell from looking at the key file, that it's ENCRYPTED using 3DES and so needs a password.  How do I get openssl to tell me that?

The best I've got so far is this:-

```
echo "\n" | openssl rsa -check -in keyfile -passin stdin
```

Which generates:-

```
unable to load Private Key
139743854057216:error:28069065:UI routines:UI_set_result:result too small:../crypto/ui/ui_lib.c:778:You must type in 4 to 1023 characters
139743854057216:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:535:
139743854057216:error:0906A065:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad decrypt:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:445:
```

Whereas if I simply run the same check on a corrupted key I get a different set of errors (not in UI routines).

But my issue with that would, be are the openssl error codes any more likely to change than the RSA key rfcs?

Not sure who it was who suggested that you can simply check to see if there are any headers inside the `-----BEGIN` section, and if there aren't any, the key is invalid.  But it led to the thought that simply checking for the `Proc-Type` line in the key, should give me an indication that the key might be signed (no headers, means it defo isn't signed).  That should be a future proof test.  No headers, means not signed.  If it has no headers and fails check, it's invalid.  If it has headers, I'll assume it needs a password.

Comment: Sadly that's not quite right.  `-----BEGIN` ... starts the wrapper, but if the contents is simply a plain, unsigned key, then it simply contains the base64 encoded key contents.  There doesn't have to be any additional fields in it.  As for a null password, passing a line return (as in my above example) is the closest I could get to a `null` password.

Comment: That said, it's probably the best suggestion, to check for additional headers.  If there are any assume it's signed, if not assume it's not signed.